# Create nested python dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am using the python code below to extract some values from an excel spreadsheet and then push them to an html page for further processing. I would like to modify the code below so that I can add additional values against each task, any help

the code below does spit out the following:

> {'line items': {'AMS Upgrade': '30667', 'BMS works':
>   '35722'}}

How can I revise the code below so that I can add 2 more values against each task i.e. **AMS Upgrade** and **BMS works**
and get the likes of (note the structure below could be wrong)

> {'line items': {'AMS Upgrade': {'30667','100%', '25799'}},{'BMS works':
>   {'10667','10%', '3572'}} }

**Code:**

```
book = xlrd.open_workbook("Example - supporting doc.xls")
first_sheet = book.sheet_by_index(-1)
nested_dict = {}
nested_dict["line items"] = {}

for i in range(21,175):
    Line_items = first_sheet.row_slice(rowx=i, start_colx=2, end_colx=8)

    if str(Line_items[0].value) and str(Line_items[1].value):
        if not Line_items[5].value ==0 : 
            nested_dict["line items"].update({str(Line_items[0].value) : str(Line_items[1].value)})

print  nested_dict
print json.dumps(nested_dict)
```

*** as requested see excel extract below

[image]

Comment: Could you give us a sample of the Excel sheet?

Comment: see update, i have attached a screeshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, each key of a dict can only be associated with a single value. However that single value can be a dict, list, set, etc that holds many values.

You will need to decide the type to use for the value associated with the `'AMS Upgrade'` key, if you want it to hold multiple values like '30667','10%', '222'.

Note: what you have written:

```
{'30667','100%', '25799'}
```

Is a set literal in Python.

Comment: so i will need to create a list with {'30667','10%', '222'}   and update the dict?